# Should a person discuss his income with his family? if yes, should he disclose to his and inlaws, if no, what are the benefits of not disclosing?

Tags: dharma

I have seen families making fun of low income individuals and also the respect given to higher income family members. Upto what extent a family should know the income of individuals and, what are the pros and cons. Seeking answers according to dharma and duties to be followed in such situations

Answer (score 3):

The amount of wealth one possesses is one of the many things that a householder must keep secret.

See the following verses from Chapter 3 of the Daksha Smriti:

> Iniquitous deeds are, again, [the following : ] Falsehood, knowing
> another's wife, taking forbidden food, knowing a woman who should not
> be known, drinking what should not be drunk, theft, committing injury,
> doing works not sanctioned in the S'ruti, transgression of a friend's
> duty, these are nine improper deeds. One should avoid them all.
>
> Longevity,
> **wealth**, weakness of a house, counsel, sexual intercourse, medicine, austerity, charity, and honour, these nine **should be
> carefully kept secret**.
>
> Freedom from a disease, satisfaction of a debt, gift, study, sale,
> giving away a daughter in marriage, dedication of a bull, secret sin,
> and the act of not being censured by others, these nine should be
> publicly done by a householder. (verses 8-14)

From this injunction we can infer that there is no harm in not telling others what one's income is.

Comment: Counsel should be kept a secret?

Comment: Yes that's what the verse says. But one might need a commentary to explain exactly what sort of advice are required to be kept secret. But I don't have any such commentary @Wikash_

Comment: Here, longevity means age? Also, weakness of house refers to house in astrology?

Comment: @Rudra Yes longevity is age (aayu) and no house refers to the home we live in and not astrological house.